# how can a client post a binary array data to the server at C#

Tags: c#, post, binary

I am trying to use the `HttpWebRequest` for posting a byteArray at  C#. i dont want to convert the bytes to string (or to `ToBase64String`). i just want to send the byteArray to the server as is. let say that my data is

```
byte[] byteArray = { 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 1, 55, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 1}
```

what should i define at the post parameters?

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"??? or request.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";???
```

I think I am missing something big....(BTW, the server is WampServer (Koana,PHP,MySQL)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to do this would be to use a `WebClient`:

```
byte[] byteArray = { 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 1, 55, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 1};

using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.UploadData(someURL, byteArray);
}
```

For binary data you usually would use `application/octet-stream` - but this is not required (depends on the server), i.e. the `WebClient` upload above does not specify a content-type header.

Comment: Hi, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
 byte[] byteArray = { 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 1, 55, 0, 1, 5, 4, 0, 1}

 using (Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
     if (requestStream.CanWrite)
         requestStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postBytes.Length);
 }
```

Comment: i think the issue is on the server side, for both ways i am getting that the $_POST is empty ( even though i can see the data at the fiddler - ��7��...). i am not sure where should i check...
any suggestion?

Comment: Are you including something like the following when you create your HttpWebRequest?  
`httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);`
httpRequest.Method = "POST";`
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";`
`httpRequest.Timeout = 5000;`

Comment: sure, the request is working fine for a string with/without the Convert.ToBase64String. I can see the string (row data) at the server DB. the thing is that  when i am trying to send the binary data (by application/x-www-form-urlencoded or by application/octet-stream) the php server varibale $_POST is empty. i am not sure where  it's being set at the server, at the request class?